# Words to call a gun?

Tags: synonyms, british-english

How would someone who goes hunting/shooting a lot describe a gun? (in UK, not USA) Any casual terms that non-hunters would not know, e.g. would they refer to the make - as in I've just bought a new "Smithy" (fictional) or whatever?
Any class based differences?

Comment: What are they hunting for?  pheasant?  deer?

Comment: Fox &/or hares. It's for a writing project.

Comment: When is the action taking place? Century/decade?

Comment: Present day really, give or take a decade or two!

Comment: So there'd probably be a discussion of the hunting ban :)   The hunter could well refer to the calibre and not to the manufacturer. There are small calibre rifles and larger calibre rifles that would serve for hunting larger game as well.  There might even be a discussion of the benefits of modern electronic devices that mimic prey-animal-in-distress calls versus old-school mechanical ones.

Comment: "Just got a new Tikka"

Comment: Thanks, so I guess something like I think I'll take the ... calibre today. I was looking for casual word, but I guess that would do.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tikka and Browning are popular.

Comment: Certainly if you go back 60 years and read detective/crime fiction you will find several terms.  Most would draw strange looks today, though.

Comment: @TRomanon The "hunting ban" does not apply to shooting. It concerns hunting with dogs. In fact when people go out shooting in Britain it is not called "hunting" as it is in America. We talk of going "shooting" and holding "a shoot".

Comment: I don't move in the circles that hunt/shoot/fish (hence a comment rather than an authoritative answer) but from TV dramas etc. it seems not uncommon to refer to a shotgun/rifle (especially a good make) by its maker. For example, the name I'm most familiar with is _Purdey_ (see [James Purdey & Sons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Purdey_%26_Sons) on Wikipedia). (_Other gun manufacturers are available_).

Comment: @WS2:  What is involved in "holding a shoot"?  Beating the brush trying to flush birds out?   Or would  hiding behind a blind waiting for a fox to appear as you make wounded animal sounds be considered "holding a shoot"?

Comment: @TRomano "They are holding a shoot on Monday on the Duke of Devonshire's property. Guns, and beaters welcome to take part. Please contact...." Could just as easily say "they will be organising a shoot".

Comment: @TRomano we also talk of "stalking" if hunting deer with a rifle (or a camera). "Holding a shoot" means organising a shooting party typically on a large country estate or farm often by the land owner for a number of guests, who may be friends or paying customers depending on the circumstances. There would typical be beaters who would flush game birds to be shot and other game like rabbits. The other time shooting is common is around harvest time when men like my dad would shoot rabbits and other small animals flushed by combines to help keep the populations down.

Comment: @TripeHound I think that if you have a particularly prestigious gun like a Purdey then yes you highlight it, like people would boast about having a Porsche or Maclaren F1. But if it's just a workaday 12guage shotgun then it's just your shotgun in the same way a Ford Escort or Vauxhall Corsa is just your car.

Comment: @TRomano Shooting at foxes has never been an organised sport in the UK. 'A shoot' normally refers to game birds.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: As I suspected.

Comment: @TripeHound I think I'm going for: "I'll take the Purdey!"  - it sounds the nearest to what I wanted.